# Using keyStore as a repository for keys and certificate

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, keystore, jks, truststore

I have ssl-certificate and private key that have been added to a keystore using a KeyTool. I'm trying to refer to this keystore

1. when setting up ssl
   metrics
2. and setting up configuration for ssl-certificate expiration using library
   **io.github.agebhar1:micrometer-certs-expiration:0.1.0.**

```
(1)
server:
  port: 8443
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-store-type: JKS
    key-store: C:\Users\myUserName\IdeaProjects\myProject\backend\src\main\resources\keystore.jks
    key-store-password: Y2hhbmdlaXQ=
    key-alias: myKey 
(2)
javax:
  net:
    ssl:
      trustStore: C:\Users\myUserName\IdeaProjects\myProject\backend\src\main\resources\keystore.jks
      trustStorePassword: changeit
      trustStoreType: JKS
```

But I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at java.base/java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.setTrustAnchors(PKIXParameters.java:200) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.<init>(PKIXParameters.java:157) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.cert.PKIXBuilderParameters.<init>(PKIXBuilderParameters.java:130) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getParameters(SSLUtilBase.java:508) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getTrustManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:439) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:253) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:104) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    ... 41 common frames omitted
```

Please tell me, can I refer the keyStore instead of trueStore, if not, tell me another library for getting metrics for ssl-certificate expiration.